# systemd socket-based DEACTIVATION

Tags: linux, sockets, systemd

I just setup a socket-based activation for my `docker.service` with systemd. If the UNIX socket is hit (read or write), the service is automatically spawned.

Now I want to automatically stop the `docker.service` unit when the socket stays idle (that means, when nobody tries to read/write) for a certain amount of time. Is it natively possible with systemd ? Or am I forced to go further with some tricks ?

It4.